# UnauthrizedAccessException when creating and writing to a folder

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a new folder in my documents and add an error log text file to it however I get an `UnauthrizedAccessException`. How can I give access to create this folder and write to it?

My code is as follows for creating my error log

```
        string currentContent = String.Empty;
        string message = string.Format("Time: {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"));




        message += "-----------------------------------------------------------";

        message += Environment.NewLine;
        message += string.Format($"Message: {errorText} {ex.Message}");

        message += Environment.NewLine;
        message += string.Format($"On Line: {currentLine} Test name {methodName}");
        string filePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + @"\ErrorLog\ErrorLogAutomatedTesting.txt";

        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            currentContent = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        }
        else
          System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        File.WriteAllText(filePath, message + currentContent);
```

Comment: Which user is the application running under? Is it different than the user account to which the "Documents" folder lives under?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a directory with the filename `ErrorLogAutomatedTesting.txt`. So it won't be a file, rather a directory. This is because the `filePath` variable contains the name of the file too. So try without it:

```
var dir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
```